# How to use ipdb with Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, ipython

GAE blocks using local libraries that it doesn't support on the server. Generally this is a good thing. Unfortunately this means that ipdb is blocked also. Adding the necessary directory for ipdb to sys.path doesn't work. It continues to give import error.

I've tried copying the ipdb+IPython folders into my gae folder, but this errors on import resource (/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/resource.so)

Another option might be to try editing GAE so it allows temporary access to local libraries?

The reason I desire ipdb is mainly for it's history and tab completion functionality.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a way to get **some** readline support with pdb on Linux systems, found here  https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/django-non-relational/C0g3ZYuhoMw

Basically install the package `rlwrap`, then run the local server similar to this:

```
rlwrap python manage.py runserver
```